# Why is it that temperature remains constant during a phase-change only if pressure is held constant?

Tags: thermodynamics

A passage in my textbook reads:

"Temperature will remain constant during an entire phase-change process if the pressure is held constant"

Why is that requirement necessary? Why is it that the temperature will not remain constant during a phase-change if pressure is allowed to vary?

Answer (score 1):

Because changing the pressure changes the phase transition temperature. For example, water boils at 100 C at 1 atm. If you increase the pressure, the boiling temperature will increase. Therefore, to keep on boiling the water, you will need to increase its temperature, otherwise you will not be able to vaporize all the water.